# Having trouble with preg_split and using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm having a tough time learning regex and `preg_split`.

I'm trying to apply what i've *learned* and can't seem to get a simple search going..

I've tried many variations, but can't separate between the bold tags, and only bold tags

```
<?php
$string = "<b>this is</b> <i>not</b> <b>bold</b>";


$find = '/<b>/';       // works as expected, separating at <b>

$find = '/<b>|<\/b>/'; // works as expected, separating at either <b> or </b>

$find = '/<b>*<\/b>/'; // why doesn't this work?

$find = '/^<b>*<\/b>/'; // why doesn't this work?

$find = '/<b>.<\/b>/'; // why doesn't this work

$result = preg_split($find, $string);

print_r($result);

?>
```

As you can see, i'm trying to incorporate the `.` `+` or start `^`/ finish `$` characters.

What am I doing *so very wrong* where it isn't working the way I expected?

Thanks for all your help!

p.s. found [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html) which is very helpful too

Comment: In what way does the second one not work?

Comment: it does, but it's not my goal. That one does work the way I expect it to.

Comment: What is your goal exactly?  You don't really say in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$find = '/<b>*<\/b>/'; // why doesn't this work?
```

Matches `"<b"`, zero or more `">"`, followed by `"</b>"`.

Perhaps you meant this:

```
$find = '/<b>.*?<\/b>/';
```

That would match `"<b>"`, followed by a string of unknown length, ending at the first occurrence of `"</b>"`. I'm not sure why you would split on that though; applied on the above you would get an array of three elements:

```
" "
"<i>not</b> "
""
```

To match everything inside `"<b>"` and `"</b>"` you need `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all('#<b>(.*?)</b>#i', $str, $matches);
// $matches[1] will contain the patterns inside the bold tag, theoratically
```

Do note that nested tags are not a great fit for regular expressions and you'd be wanting to use [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/domdocument).

---

```
$find = '/^<b>*<\/b>/'; // why doesn't this work?
```

Matches `"<b"` at the start of the string, zero or more `">"`, followed by `"</b>"`.

```
$find = '/<b>.<\/b>/'; // why doesn't this work
```

Matches `"<b>"`, followed by any character, followed by `"</b>"`.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful..it is making sense now. I completely agree in hindsight that this example produces a counter-intuitive result hahah

Comment: If i wanted to get the opposite of `<b>.*?<\/b>` what could I do? i.e. return everything within `<b>...</b>`?

Answer (score 3):

The first two "why doesn't this work" are matching `<b` followed by zero or more `>` characters, followed by `</b>`. The last one matches `<b>` then any single character then `</b>`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but this would split on start and end bold tags: `<\/?b>` - it matches `<`, followed by an optional `/`, followed by `b>`.

Comment: awesome! that's what I wanted...so what would i use instead of an asterisk to signal 0 or more of anything? would that be `<b>*$<b\/>`?

Comment: `.*?` would work, it matches any number of any character, but lazily (so it stops at the first `</b>` and not the last one).

Comment: ok I think i've been confused on the orientation of which way (left/right) those characters work. Thanks! I've got to find better learning material for this :/